# place border around circle/disc which holds text with css

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

Using CSS, I have a display that places text in a circle/disc.

Here is an example of what I have:

[image]

But I am struggling at placing a red border around the circle/disc.

I have searched SO & Google, looked at plenty of examples, but I cannot configure my css class code to have a border.

Hoping that someone can suggest an answer.

Here is my html:

```css
span.circle_standard {
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 3em;
  -moz-border-radius: 3em;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3em;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 6em;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 6em;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-4 padding-bottom-10" dir="ltr" style="direction: ltr; background-color: yellow; text-align: center;">
  <div class="row">
    <span class="circle_standard" dir="ltr" style="direction: ltr;">WWWWW</span>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <b>Descriptive Details Here</b>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you not use the `border` style? `border: solid 1px #000` would make a 1px black border around the circle. I've used this for something very similar to what you're talking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [box-shadow property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow) to do this:

```css
span.circle_standard {
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 3em;
  -moz-border-radius: 3em;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3em;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 6em;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 6em;
  box-shadow:  0 0 0 4px red;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-4 padding-bottom-10" dir="ltr" style="direction: ltr; background-color: yellow; text-align: center;">
  <div class="row">
    <span class="circle_standard" dir="ltr" style="direction: ltr;">WWWWW</span>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <b>Descriptive Details Here</b>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.circle {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  border-radius:100px;
  font-size:20px;
  color:#fff;
  text-align:center;
  background:#000;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 8px;
  border-color: #6CB670;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"></div>
```

Check in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Skramewell/0v70t3zn/).

Comment: The problem with using the border is that it actually only looks like it works but the rounded corners cause an issue. jsfiddle.net/j08691/bhptykn4/2